# .net Workflow Foundation Editor

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation

Is it possible to integrate the .net workflow foundation editor (from VisualStudio) or a similar control into an other application?

Otherwise i have to program it by my self.

I have to realize an interactive diagram chart in which the user can put in new actions, parameter and something.

Thanks for your information!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is! :)

The technique is called "Workflow Designer Re-Hosting", and you can read more about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835242.aspx).

Comment: Here is an implemented example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480213.aspx thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. In the project I am currently working on, we use the Workflow Foundation designer in a WinForms front end. You can see a screenshot [here](http://www.streamworks.de/Solution_streamworks.pdf). But I cannot tell you exactly how it is done because I joined to project when this was already done.